# H-bridge logic driver in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, logic-gates

I am trying to come up with a driver logic for an H-bridge (seen in the image attached) which would provide a single-ended or a differential pulse based on a user choice.

[image]

**Input signals:** clk (clock, duration can vary), por (power-on-reset), en (enable for the circuit), sel (select the mode, 1 for differential).

**Outputs:** A1, A2, B1 and B2

**Terms:** low - 0, high - 1

**Operational logic:**

Initial conditions: A1 and B1 are high if A2 and B2 are low (prevents crowbar current).

If 'por' and 'en' are high, the circuit is enabled.

If 'sel' is **low**, single ended drive is run (same for A and B branches, so will just describe A):

1. When 'clk' goes high, A1 goes low; A2 goes high, but only when A1 is low.
2. When 'clk' goes low, A2 goes low; A1 goes high, but only when A2 is low.

If 'sel' is **high**, differential drive is run:

1. When 'clk' goes high, A1 goes low; A2 goes high, but only when A1 is low; B2 is low and B1 is high.
2. When 'clk' goes low, both A2 and B1 go low; both A1 and B2 go high, but only when A2/B1 are low.

The code I currently have is:

```
module non_ov_gen (
input clk, por, en, sel,
output a1out, a2out, b1out, b2out
);

wire a1 = a1out, a2 = a2out, b1 = b1out, b2 = b2out;

case (por && en) // if power-on-reset goes high, initiallize the device

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (sel)        // if differential drive is selected
            assign a1out = 0;       // turn off a1
            assign b2out = 0;
            assign b1out = !b1;
            assign a2out = !a1;     // turn on a2 if a1 is low
        else
            assign a1out = 0;       // turn off a1
            assign a2out = !a1;     // turn on a2 if a1 is off
            assign b1out = 0;       // turn off b1
            assign b2out = !b1;     // turn on b2 if b1 is off
        end     
    end

    always @(negedge clk)
    begin   
        if (sel)
            assign a2out = 0;
            assign b1out = 0;
            assign a1out = !a2;
            assign b2out = !b1;
        else
            assign a2out = 0;       // turn off a1
            assign a1out = !a2;     // turn on a2 if a1 is off
            assign b2out = 0;       // turn off b1
            assign b1out = !b2;

default // set initial states
    assign a2out = 0;
    assign a1out = !a2;
    assign b2out = 0;
    assign b1out = !b2;
    end
endcase
```

This is the first time for me using Verilog and I am confused whether this is appropriate or not and whether I am taking the right approach.

Can you please help me out with getting this to work?

Comment: First, you can't put an `assign` inside a procedural block. You use `assign` outside a procedural block when you want a *continuous assignment*, that is, when you want the left side to be updated whenever any of the signals on the right side change.

Comment: Plus you are using sensitivity on both clock edges for the same signal which is not typically usuable for synthesis.

Comment: Then you have a random case statement outside a procedural block.

Comment: You have no endmodule line, nor begin-end statements (bar one random end on the penultimate line).

Comment: Basically I'd suggest finding a tutorial on Verilog and following that before you try your own designs. HDLs are not something you can just jump in at the deep end with, as you basically need to forget anything you know about regular programming.

Answer (score 1):

Without wanting to sound rude, there is a lot syntactically wrong with the code you have presented, and that is before getting down to the logic of what you are trying to do.

Basically I'd suggest finding a tutorial on Verilog and following that before you try your own designs. For example [this](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day.html) is a good starting point to get the very basics.

HDLs are not something you can just jump in at the deep end with, as you basically need to forget anything you know about regular programming.

Comment: Additionally, problems of this type typically get solved with a small MCU rather than HDL-described logic.  In theory it would be possible to use a CPLD (or make an dedicated chip) but that usually a more complex development process in the first case, and an exorbitantly more expensive one in the second, neither warranted except in unique circumstances.